# Can a property be "idiosyncratic to" an object?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

Is it grammatically correct to write `(property) is idiosyncratic to (object)` in the same way that one could write `(property) is unique to (object)`?

For example

> This feature is idiosyncratic to the Apple Macintosh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems so. The Oxford English Dictionary has this 2002 citation from the ‘Atlanta Journal and Constitution’:

> The use of panel techniques also enables us to adjust for factors
>   idiosyncratic to each county and for any national time trends in
>   homicide rates.

It may not, however, be common. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has only 16 instances, and the British National Corpus, 6.

Answer (score 0):

It has the same basic meaning, though it carries a certain amount of value judgement. I take **idiosyncratic** as being somewhat negative, with **unique** being somewhat positive.